# Show a map from $\mathbb{P}^2$ to $\mathbb{P}^2$ is injective

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, projective-space

I have a map $F: \mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^2$ defined by $F(x_0 : x_1 : x_2) = (x_0^2 + x_2^2 : x_0 x_1 + x_1 x_2 : x_0 x_2 + x_1^2)$ and I need to show it is well defined and smooth. I already proved this, but now I need to show that the restriction of $F$ to the chart $U_0 = \{(x_0 : x_1 : x_2) \in \mathbb{P}^2 | x_0 \neq 0\}$ is injective. I have tried to put $F(x_0 : x_1 : x_2) = F(y_0 : y_1 : y_2)$ and deduce that $(x_0 : x_1 : x_2) = (y_0 : y_1 : y_2)$ (as points of $\mathbb{P}^2$), but couldn't conclude. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have to show that it is a local diffeomorphism?

Comment: I noticed now I have to check whether it is an injective immersion or not. I just discovered it is not since it is not an immersion, so exercise wise I have found an answer, though I would still like to find out if it is indeed injective or not.

Comment: Have you showed why it is not an immersion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a point $p\in U_0\implies F(p)\in\tilde {U_0}$, so the local representative of the map is $\hat F=\tilde \psi_0\circ F\circ \psi_0$.
If we take a point $(u,v)\in\psi_0(U_0)$, we have
$$\hat F(u,v)=\tilde \psi_0\circ F(1:u:v)=\tilde \psi_0(1+v^2:u+uv:v+u^2)= \bigg(\dfrac{u(v+1)}{1+v^2},\dfrac{v+u^2}{1+v^2}\bigg)\implies$$$$ \hat F \in\mathcal C^{\infty}(\psi_0(U_0)).$$
The map $F_{*p}:T_p\mathbb P^2\to T_{F(p)}\mathbb P^2$ is locally represented by
$$J_{\hat F}\vert_p=\begin{pmatrix}\nabla \hat F_1(u,v)\\\nabla\hat F_2(u,v) \end{pmatrix}\Bigg\vert_p$$
but if we evaluate $J_{\hat F}$ in $(0,-1)\implies \text {rk}(J_{\hat F})<2\implies F$ is not an immersion.
Take now two points $(1:1:2)$, then $F(1:1:2)=(5:3:3)=F(2:1:1)=(5:3:3)$ but since $\nexists\lambda\in\mathbb R$ s.t.
$(2:1:1)=\lambda(1:1:2)\implies F$  can't be an injective immersion.

Comment: Thank you! I had already showed it was not an immersion exactly in the same way as you did, but I was so convinced it was injective that I did not even try to show it wasn't. I misread the text of the exercise...

Comment: I have a question. Are you sure the rank of the Jacobian is not 2 evaluating at $(0,0)$? Maybe I made some mistake but in $(0,0)$ the Jacobian is the identity matrix to me. The point $(0,-1)$ works though.

Comment: It can be! I edit it